# Publishing bitbucket to digital ocean

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, digital-ocean

I'm essentially trying to understand the concept of git using bitbucket; I've been practicing version control by modifying files between my local and bitbucket accounts which has proven helpful.

Now I'm trying to work out how you would push the files from a remote repo in bitbucket (or i guess GitHub or the like) to a cloud hosting solution such as digital ocean. Is that even recommended? I can't really google it because result come up as thinking I mean the bitbucket server, or want to host a site on bitbucket itself. I'm not sure if you would ask digital ocean to 'fetch' the files, or there is options within Bitbucket to push remotely and act intermediately.

Comment: Did this work out for you? Or was it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use post-receive hook in `.git\hooks`. The content of post-receive should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/droplet/repo --git-dir=/bitbucket/repo checkout -f
```

Now after you push changes to bitbucket, it will redeploy to droplet.

More detail, you can refer [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new remote branch in your local repository.

This is how you will do it. [git remote add](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/)
(You will need a repository ready on the remote location)

Note that in the example above they add a remote repository called origin. You might want to change it to something else if you have cloned the repository from bitbucket.

After that whenever you do any operation regarding a remote repository you will have to mention which remote repository.

Ex for push

```
git push origin master
git push <remote_repo> <remote_branch>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please take a look at the following question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66858780/9409877