# How to deploy a Dockerized Symfony app to Digital Ocean

Tags: symfony, docker, digital-ocean

I'm exploring the world of Docker and now I'm at the point of publishing the app to Digital Ocean.

I created a simple app with Symfony without any code that, when accessed, simply shows the default Symfony's welcome page.

Now I'd like to deploy it to Digital Ocean (or any other service, this is just a test).

I created a `docker-compose.yaml` file in which I create two services: one for the webserver and one for the MySQL database:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  # "php" was "language" in previous example
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/build/php/Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:8100:80"

  # Configure the database
  mysql:
    build: docker/build/mysql
    ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:3307:3306"
    volumes:
    - ./docker/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Now, how can I deploy this to Digital Ocean?

I need to understand the flow.

This is what I imagine I should do:

1. Clone my repo from BitBucket to the Digital Ocean droplet (like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42055142/publishing-bitbucket-to-digital-ocean))
2. Run `docker-compose build` on the droplet
3. Run `docker-compose up -d` on the droplet.

Is this the correct flow?

I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just done this. Use an existing project (like https://github.com/coloso/symfony-docker). Here in the docker-compose file, the "virtual" symfony folder in the php container is synchronized with a local "symfony" folder, so you can work as normal, once you have started everything. When the work is done, just commit the project (including the docker files) to github (private repository) und clone it on a digital oceans docker droplet and run here "composer install" in your php container instead of "composer create-project ...". It's a really nice an fast system.